# LWP post returns empty files while curl works fine

Tags: php, perl, curl, lwp

I found that my upload perl returns empty files on my apache, but posting it with CURL works fine:

```
@FILES = qw (o1.tmp o2.tmp o3.tmp); 

foreach $filename (@FILES) {

$ua=LWP::UserAgent->new;

$proxy = "http://$USERNAME:$PASSWORD\@$PROXY_ADD";


$ua->proxy(['http', 'https'], $proxy); 

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(10);
my $url = "http://www.XXXXXXXXX.es/handler.php";
my $picture = $filename;
my %args;
my $field_name = "userfile";
my $buf ;
my $buf_ref = $args{'buf'} || \$buf ;


my $value = read_file( $picture , binmode => ':raw' , scalar_ref => 1 );

my $response = $ua->post( $url,
        Content_Type => 'form-data',
        Content => [ $field_name => ["$picture"] ]
        );
print $response->content;
}
```

Returns empty files:

```
root@dasdasd:/var/www/upload# ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 0 oct 30 20:08 tmp_30-10-2013_0808pm_5554.tmp
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 0 oct 30 20:08 tmp_30-10-2013_0808pm_8437.tmp
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 0 oct 30 20:08 tmp_30-10-2013_0808pm_8629.tmp
```

But with this cURL code:

```
XXX-MacBook-Pro:Desktop xxxxxx$ curl -X PUT --header "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" --header "Name: 1" --data-binary "@2.gif" -v http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.es/handler.php
```

Works:

```
root@Arvaro:/var/www/upload# ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 0 oct 30 20:08 tmp_30-10-2013_0808pm_5554.tmp
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 0 oct 30 20:08 tmp_30-10-2013_0808pm_8437.tmp
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 0 oct 30 20:08 tmp_30-10-2013_0808pm_8629.tmp
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 6 oct 30 20:40 tmp_30-10-2013_0840pm_1978.tmp
                              ^^^
                           not empty
```

Anyone can put some light here?

Thanks

Comment: You use PUT with `curl`, but POST with LWP. You prove a name header with `curl`, but not with LWP.

Comment: Your code LWP code has a lot of dead code, including `$ua->proxy(['http', 'https'], $proxy);`.

Comment: What's the HTTP status ling of the response?

Comment: $ua->proxy(['http', 'https'], $proxy); is used for basic auth on a proxy. I think is needed. About the rest... sure.. tons of dead code. I dont know the HTTP status of the response. I saw no response on the output of the script. About the put/post... I can try using PUT in LWP..but I dont know the correct way to do it. I can try a code if you suggest any (thanks btw).

Comment: I've tried on CURL to use POST instead of CURL and works fine. I found also that my files are limited to 8192 bytes.. but actually my php.ini is configured to accept close to 20Mb...

Comment: If `->proxy` is needed, then there's you're problem. You didn't use it for the `$ua` you use to `post`.

Comment: CAn you post an example?.. Not sure If I'm following you

Comment: I said you didn't call ->proxy on the second $ua you created. What do you mean, you want an example of that?!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you're posting file **name** but **not content** of this file. Next in your cURL you're using some headers...

I think you need something like this:

```
$ua->default_header('Name' => "1");


my $response = $ua->post( $url,
        Content_Type => 'multipart/form-data',
        Content => [ $field_name => $value ]
        );
print $response->content;
```

Comment: Sure that the issue is here.. but I'm not following what to add on $value, I mean in my example it suppose to post o1.txt o2.txt and o3.txt... since $picture is $filename that comes from the bucle.

Comment: @alvgarci You can't just give the name of the file to upload, you have to actually read it, and send that.

Comment: Sure. I got it already. I was working on it. The point is..do I have to do a typical do while loop reading all the file line per line and do a post on each line.. or do I have to dump all post content to a variable and post it?..